# What is an alternative for lookbehind with C++ RegEx?

Tags: regex, string, c++11, regex-lookarounds

I am using the following pattern:

```
(?<=<)(?<!>).*?q.*?(?!<)(?=>)
```

It uses positive and negative lookahead and lookbehind to match the literal `q` that is enclosed in matching brackets.

`std::regex` does not support lookbehind. So what would be a good alternative?

Comment: It is a very weird pattern that won't work if there are several `<...>` substrings in the same line. If you still need this regex, you'd use `<(.*?q.*?)>` and grab `smatch_obj.str(1)`. However, `<([^>q]*q[^>]*)>` will perform better and will be more precise.

Comment: `boost` supports that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `(?<=<)(?<!>)` is equal to `(?<=<)` (since a `<` is required immediately to the left of the current location, there cannot be any `>`) and `(?!<)(?=>)` is equal to `(?=>)` (same logic applies here, as `>` must be immediately to the right, there won't be any `<`). The first `.*?` will not match the shortest substring possible, it will literally find its way to the first `q` that is followed with any 0+ chars up to the first `>`.  So, the pattern is hardly working for you even in the lookbehind-supporting engine.

I'd rather use `<([^<>q]*q[^<>]*)>` regex with a *capturing group*  and literal consuming `<` and `>` symbols at the start/end of the expression:

```
std::regex r("<([^<>q]*q[^<>]*)>");
std::string s = "<adqsdq<><abc>5<abq>6<qaz> <hjfffffffk>";
for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
                         i != std::sregex_iterator();
                         ++i)
{
    std::cout << (*i).str(1)  << srd::endl;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/aVNgq1)

Output: `abq` and `qaz`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, problem with your regex is that it doesnt take into account the presence of another bracket so for instance`<adqsdq<>` should not match because there is a left bracket inside a left/right. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Ok, use `<([^<>q]*q[^<>]*)>`. [Your regex did not account for that](https://regex101.com/r/EbY5ld/1).

Comment: Check the answer now, I have updated it with a regex that does not match the string you provided.

Comment: Perhaps I should post this as another question, but how do you replace captured groups only in C++ RegEx.

Comment: No, you do not replace capture groups only, you capture what you need to keep and only match what you need to remove. If you need to replace something specific inside a capture group you need a callback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142190/discussion-between-joey-and-wiktor-stribizew).